# Google script not showing jQuery layouts when uploaded to Google script HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

On my html editor this code works but when I upload it with my Code.gs, which is used for google script.

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('hh');
 }
```

It should show the same layout as it did in my html editor but it looks different. You can see it here:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwM0y5y3kkgWAoPb99hXwdJKTpvt3hvXwWLHvzehbcw/dev

```
<title>jQuery Mobile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    </script>
    <body>
       <!-- label text -->
       <div data-role="page">
          <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
             <h1>Example</h1>
             <form id="form" name="form">
          </div>
          <div style="width:auto; margin:20px;padding-top:30px;">
          <label for="howMuch_1">How much?</label>
          <input id ="howMuch_1" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
          <label for="howMany_1">How many tickets?</label>
          <input id ="howMany_1" type="range" min="1" max="50" value="1">
          <label for="lastNumber_1">Last number?</label>
          <input id ="lastNumber_1" type="range" max="700" min="1" value="1">
          <button id="add" ></button>
          </div>
          </form>
       </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks different on the same device/browser?  I can't view your app without permission, and I don't want to request permission.  You can either make the app accessible to everyone without needing permission, or post some screen shot here.

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/csiuh9yyn/image.jpg here is the link. Thanks.

Comment: What looks different?  We would need to see a comparison of two different things.

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/49d3kchc5/Screen_Shot_2014_07_08_at_11_43_43_AM.png 
This image shows right things.
This one doesn't 
s17.postimg.org/csiuh9yyn/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that CAJA has sanitized and stripped out some of the functionality of jQuery Mobile.  But that's just a guess.  Try using:

```
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('hh')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the NATIVE mode
    .setTitle('Title of your app')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
```

Setting the sandbox Mode to NATIVE might help, but I can't guarantee it.

References:

[Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)

Quote:

> To protect users from being served malicious HTML or JavaScript, Apps
>   Script relies on the Caja Compiler to sanitize and sandbox
>   HTML-service web apps or custom user interfaces for Google Docs,
>   Sheets, and Forms.

[Apps Script HTML Service Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)

Comment: No that didn't work. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see what caja thinks of your code by pasting it into the caja playground, which you can find at http://caja.appspot.com/

I tried your source, and found this error

> Uncaught script error: 'TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search
>   for 'pushState' in undefined' in source:
>   'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js' at
>   line: 1

There is also an existing app script issue about jquerymobile compatibility here - i recommend you star and follow

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1665&can=1&q=jquery&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Answer (score 0):

try the below

- .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
- use the jQuery libraries from ajax.googleapis.com instead of jquery.com

  [ ref: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-mobile ]

EDIT: see also [JQuery Mobile with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922088/jquery-mobile-with-google-apps-script)